# If current time is 1 or more days earlier than starts_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an exam starts_at field, and what I want to do is, if current date is 1 day or more before exam starts_at I want to redirect to somewhere else. And if current date is the same day as when the exam starts_at I want to redirect to the exam page....for now I just want to get the if statement correct, I will put the redirect later.

Here is my controller.

**Student Session Controller**

```
class StudentSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_student_session
  before_filter :config_opentok, except: :update
  before_action :try_authenticate_user!, except: :mobile
  before_action :check_compatability, except: :mobile

  def show
    @session = @student_session.session
    @session_id = @session.session_id
    @token = @opentok.generate_token @session_id, :data => "#{@student_session.id}"

    # If Time.now is 1 or more days before exam starts_at show message
    if (@session.exam.starts_at =< Time.now)
      render :text => "OK"
    else
      render :text => "Not ok"
    end

    if @student_session.student.present?
      #UserMailer.mobile_link(current_user.email, current_user.name, @student_session).deliver
    else
      #UserMailer.mobile_link(@student_session.email, @student_session.email, @student_session).deliver
    end

    ua = UserAgent.parse(request.user_agent)
    @student_session.operating_system = ua.os
    @student_session.browser = ua.browser
    @student_session.browser_version = ua.version.to_s
    @student_session.save

    render  layout: "application_no_header"
  end

  def mobile
    @session = @student_session.session
    @session_id = @session.session_id
    @token = @opentok.generate_token @session_id, :data => "#{@student_session.id}_mobile"
    render layout: false
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @student_session.update(student_session_params)
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_student_session
      @student_session = StudentSession.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def student_session_params
      params.require(:student_session).permit(:session_status, :publisher_status, :proctor_status, :mobile_status)
    end

    def config_opentok
      @opentok ||= OpenTok::OpenTok.new APP_CONFIG['opentok']['api_key'], APP_CONFIG['opentok']['secret']
    end

    def try_authenticate_user!
      if @student_session.student.present?
        authenticate_user!
      end
    end

    def check_compatability
      user_agent = UserAgent.parse(request.user_agent)

      # http://tokbox.com/opentok/requirements/
      unless (user_agent.browser == 'Chrome'  and user_agent.version.to_a.first >= 23) or
          (user_agent.browser == 'Firefox' and user_agent.version.to_a.first >= 22)
        redirect_to '/browser'
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use:

```
if @session.exam.starts_at.to_date == Date.today
  # go to exam
elsif @session.exam.starts_at.to_date < Date.today
  # go to place before the exam
else
  # go to place after the exam
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((@session.exam.starts_at - Time.now).to_i / 1.day) >= 1
      render :text => "OK"
else
      render :text => "Not ok"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

As you're using rails you can do

```
if (Time.now >= (@session.exam.starts_at - 1.day) )
  render :text => "OK"
else
  render :text => "Not ok"
end
```

Comment: Error: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.

Comment: I got rid of render  layout: "application_no_header"